# What PRNG function is this?

Tags: algorithms, c, random-number-generation, assembly

This is a 16-bit PRNG function, transcribed from assembly to C for easier reading:

```c
#define LOW(exp)  ((exp) & 0x00FF)
#define HIGH(exp) (((exp) & 0xFF00) >> 8)

uint16_t prng(uint16_t v) {

    uint16_t low  = LOW(v);
    uint16_t high = HIGH(v);

    uint16_t mul_low  = low  * 5;
    uint16_t mul_high = high * 5;

    // need to check for overflow, since final addition is adc as well
    uint16_t v1    = LOW(mul_high) + HIGH(mul_low) + 1;
    uint8_t  carry = HIGH(v1) ? 1 : 0;

    uint16_t v2 = (LOW(v1) << 8) + LOW(mul_low);

    return (v2 + 0x11 + carry);
}
```

<sup>Original  transcription by @sagara, according to @EternisedDragon; minor edits by me. Assembly and some explanations available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745601/how-is-the-carry-flag-being-set-in-this-assembly-code.</sup>

I've been trying to identify this PRNG, wanting to find out if it falls under a common classification. I've been going through [Wikipedia's list of random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators), like the [Linear feedback shift register algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register), but all of these seem way more complex than the simple function above.

**Does this function look familiar to anyone?**

I'd like to research the properties of this PRNG but first wanted to see if there's any existing literature.

Comment: You'll be more likely to get an answer to this if you can translate your C code into a mathematical formula for what the C code computes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little playing with the sequence of numbers generated by the C code shows that the sequence is

$z_{i+1}=5z_{i}+273 \mod 2^{16}$

This is a linear congruential generator (LCG).  It's easy to show that this LCG has full period (See theorem 7.1 in Law's *Simulation Modeling and Analysis, 5th ed.* and check the three conditions.)

I can't find the generator in any of the references that I checked, but that doesn't mean it hasn't been published somewhere.  It will suffer from all of the faults of other LCG's (in particular it will do badly on tests of uniformity in higher dimensions.)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this! Your formula did appear to match the outputs, but when I started investigating some inconsistencies, I found that the formula failed to reproduce 766 of 65536 outputs. I found that the interval between 13055 and 13056 is 6 rather than the 5, rendering the formula off-by-1 until reaching 13311, where the interval to 13312 is another anomaly of 4. Such off-by-1 stretches reappear between 26163..26367, 39270..39423, 52377..52479, and finally, 65484..65535, adding up to 766 inputs.

Comment: I wonder whether the algorithm can still be treated as an LCG despite these offsets. I'll have to learn a little more about what makes an LCG an LCG and how its properties have been derived.

Comment: [Here's an Ideone](http://ideone.com/MSkbSa), for convenience of testing.

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether the problem with this has to do with the C translation of the original assembler code producing different output from the assembler code or whether this is also true of the original assembler code.  It could also be that the assembler code was a bungled attempt to produce this sequence that just didn't work right.

Comment: I've found that the anomalous intervals occur at the boundaries where `LOW(high*5)+HIGH(low*5)` first overflows into the 17th bit, from which point `carry` is set, or, first _stops_ overflowing into the 17th bit, from which point `carry` is reset. At these transitions, the `carry` causes the result to shift or unshift by 1. I believe that it _was_ a mistake, because this could have been avoided easily by replacing the final ADC (add-with-carry) op with a normal ADD in [the assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36745601/925913). (Why would an "almost-LCG" be intended? Would you agree?)

Comment: Hm, I found [Add with Carry Generator (Marsaglia and Zaman, page 464)](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoap/1177005878)? (Incidentally, this paper was published in 1991, and the assembly code for this ROM was developed from 1992 to 1994.) This led me to Multiply with Carry Generators, which is what I'm starting to think this is.

Comment: I think it's most likely just a mistake in the implementation of the LCG.  It still could be an error in the translation of the original assembler code into C.

Comment: I never found any more evidence that it was intended. In fact, I'm now sure it was a mistake too. Turns out the 65xx family of processors didn't have an ADD operation! So the programmer probably meant to call CLC (clear carry) before the ADC, but either failed or did not recognize the importance of doing so. Marking your answer as accepted, thank you very much.